# Im using css Grid and Tailwind to create a simple Footer but there's line appearing in a place where it shoiuldn't and I would like to know ¿why?

Tags: css, vue.js, grid, css-grid, tailwind-css

I'm using CSS grid to do something very simple, and Tailwind to style ( in which I'm really new so I'm probably making a silly mistake).
This is the result I'm getting:
[image]

Pretty good because It's almost identical to the original design which I'm following but the **line on the left** => **Shouldn't be there**.
This is my code right now:

```
<nav
          class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6 divide-x text-white sm:flex sm:justify-center sm:text-md lg:justify-end sm:divide-white"
        >
          <div
            v-for="item in [navigation[0], navigation[1]]"
            :key="item.name"
            class="text-center w-auto px-3 divide-x"
          >
            <a :href="item.href" class="text-white">
              {{ t(item.name) }}
            </a>
          </div>
          <div
            v-for="item in [navigation[2], navigation[3]]"
            :key="item.name"
            class="text-center w-auto px-3 divide-x"
          >
            <a :href="item.href" class="text-white">
              {{ t(item.name) }}
            </a>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

I also tried this which is basically the same I think:
[image]

Hope you can tell me what's wrong, and how I remove that ugly & unnecessary line. Thxs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works as intended. The key to your problem is `divide-x` [class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/divide-width) - it adds left border for every element but first. You have 4 element therefore there are 3 dividers which is correct. It does not smart enough to understand your layout - it simply adds border. To solve this you may manually remove this border from 3rd element (element where you don't need this border) on mobile and bring it back on larger devices like

```html
<div class="w-auto px-3 text-center border-none sm:border-solid">
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/IWcMGnkUyn)

Note: you don't need to add `divide-x` class to any child. Only parent wrap need this

Another way is to remove `divide-x` completely and set `border-l border-l-white` manually on every element you need on every breakpoint. This way you'll have more control over layout but also more classes to add

P.S. Same "problem" applies for `space-y-n` and `space-x-n` utilities - sometimes when elements being wrapped you may see unnecessary margin